# To disable View - Explorer Bar - Folders Option in Internet Explorer 6.0

Tags: security, internet-explorer, windows-registry, group-policy

Are there any Registry Settings or GP's that I can use to ensure that View - Explorer Bar - Folders option is disabled in IE 6.0 for a particular user alone.

We have already disabled the Address Bar, F3 for Search Options, View - Explorer Bar - Search option, Ctrl + E

Comment: Update #1: I happened to find this in one of the Q & A websites. I am reproducing it here

Go to
HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\CLSID\{EFA24E64-B078-11d0-89E4-00C04FC9E26E} and make a backup of it, then delete it. 
When Folders is chosen, sidebar is blank. Although this works, I am not sure that this is the right way of implementing it, as I am doing just for one user on Citrix.

Comment: Put that as an answer! If no-one else comes up with anything better you should then accept it. Though I'm not sure completely removing the class is the best approach... maybe a Windows update might re-register it?

Comment: But it is so *not* an answer. Deleting CLSID's, definitely No. Maybe I would have put it as an answer if it was like adding a DWORD and changing it. Say, like what I have in SF. 
http://serverfault.com/questions/93851/group-policy-to-prevent-accessing-other-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not able to find out an exact way of disabling the View-->Explorer Bar-->Folders, but if you run Internet Explorer in Kiosk mode, it will not display the Menu Bar and users will not be able to choose it.

Now, what about keyboard shortcuts. I am not aware of any, and neither does Google. So, I guess that would be the best possible solution.

Only one hitch though, how will you quit the session? You have to use Alt + F4 to quit it.